# Making a Most Active Contributors report on all sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, per-site-meta

On Ask Different we have every month, a report posted on Meta for the whole month.

This includes:

- Reputation stats
- Most active users stats
- Stats for all review queues
- Highest voted questions
- Highest voted anawers
- Highest viewed question
- Moderator stats

This report is really good for:

- Rewarding active users
- Seeing review queues statistics
- Seeing moderator activity like flag handling time
- Seeing the food questions and answers

Example reports:

[Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - November 2018](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-november-2018)

[Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - December 2018](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-december-2018)

[Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - January 2019](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-january-2019)

So I suppose bringing them to all sites. A moderator would need to volunteer to do that once a month. Every sites report could be slightly different as long as it aims to see everyone's success and the moderators work.

Note this is optional and just a suggestion.

Comment: Ask Different has plenty of people on meta ([home page](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/) can only display a few month's activity) while some sites have very, very, very little meta activity (where all the activity from the past one or two *years* fits on the home page of some metas—even 5 years, everything, in the case of [one site](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/)). On these sites I think it would probably be a waste of time since nobody is on meta.

Comment: Also worth to mention similar feature (ranking users based on overall activity) already exists in SE, built-in, though hidden. To reach it, you have to manually write such URL: https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation (i.e. adding `?tab=participation` to a main site users list page)

Comment: The problem with these "competitions" is that it encourages production (not always a bad thing) but not quality...

Comment: @ShadowWizard what does participation mean there: the number of visits, comments or posts, or is it a combination of all three?

Comment: @Mari https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145151/how-is-meta-participation-calculated (same on main sites, it's just not linked.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the link, interesting!

Comment: @Sue I was sarcastic towards a situation where a "top user" is being suspended. Such situation simply shouldn't happen, so it was overwhelming. Didn't mean to point fingers.

Answer (score 18):

I disagree with this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), because this is not something that should be decided on Meta SE and then become mandatory on all stacks in some "top-down approach".

It's commendable that a mod on Ask Different volunteers to compile these reports and it may have a positive effect, but it also seems to be *a lot of work*. If someone else gets inspired by this and also wants to write such reports, they should be free to do that. But every stack should decide that for themselves and no one should feel that they have to.

Moderators have other duties and should not be burdened with having to post these reports. They surely also have a life outside SE and it may deter good candidates in the future from running for mod, when they know they may have to write these reports monthly.

It also largely depends on site activity - almost no meta activity means few people will likely read it (I know stacks with almost no meta activity). And the more activity on a site, especially a more subjective one, may mean having to clean up more comments etc. so the workload for mods becomes even greater.