# Which site in the Stack Exchange network has the highest ratio of meta-traffic to main-site-traffic?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, statistics, traffic

Which site in the Stack Exchange network has the highest and lowest traffic on its **meta** site **relative** to its main site?

At first I was thinking that Stack Overflow had the highest ratio, as its meta site is really active. But then again, its main site has questions pouring in every minute, so it could also be that it has one of the lowest ratios.

---

**Edit:**

As for the comment

> what is traffic? Questions per day? Posts per day? Something else?

I honestly don't know. I was hoping that someone who knows the site better would have an answer, possibly from an existing *"How to determine the level of traffic of a Stack Exchange site"* meta post that I failed to dig up.

Comment: what is traffic? Questions per day? Posts per day? Something else?

Comment: This one must be highest because this site is it's own meta ;-) Or maybe lowest because there is no main site.

Comment: I was going to point that out. Ninjaed. Or maybe Metaed.

Comment: There is an easy definition of activity on meta: everybody how got an invite for the famous 0.015% potluck -- these queries might give some inspiration how to measure meta activity https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387772/2777074

Comment: I think explaining what you hope to understand by measuring "traffic" would help clarify your question. Saying "I don't know what I meant when I used the word traffic" doesn't really help me understand what you're asking for. I can make a reasonable  guess, but it would be better if I didn't have to guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can help if you're interested in the total amount of views (of questions). [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1557548/main-vs-meta-traffic) is a query which does that:

[image: Community Building has the lowest ratio at 9.17. Code Golf is 4th at 23.94 and also has the 3rd highest number of meta site views.]

I'm not sure what to make of the results. I do know that Code Golf has a popular Sandbox on its meta...

@ColleenV suggested to look at *votes* rather than *views*; [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1557591/main-vs-meta-votes) compares the total number of up- and downvotes:

[image: Hardware Recommendations has the lowest ratio at 5.86 and is followed closely by Community Building at 5.94.]

If we look at [participation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097/295232) (minus edits, if I try to include those my SEDE query times out) in the past 60 days, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1557655/main-vs-meta-participation) gives the following result:

[image: Windows Phone has the lowest ratio at 8. Language Learning has the next lowest ratio but is larger by more than 40 at 48.17.]

Comment: If you're wondering why [Cardano.SE] and [ConLang.SE] have the same results: [blame this editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/359796/6). Will be fixed next Sunday ...

Comment: I'm not sure views is the right metric. Wouldn't search engines be more likely to hit on the main site for a topic than the meta? I don't think there is any way to get just community member traffic though. Maybe votes cast would be a better ratio to measure participation differences between main and meta?

Comment: Me neither. I'm better at writing SEDE queries than at determining a good metric ...

Comment: I think....it should be the level of activity per month (numbers of votes, questions and answers posted) on main site compared to meta.

Comment: Activity per month won't work for [certain communities](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) ...

Comment: Definitely not the right metric. We want something the correlates main and meta activity of active users, not viewers. And I cant think of a way to do that.

Comment: FWIW, I chose # of views because the OP mentioned 'traffic', not 'participation'.

Comment: Yeah the question isn't clear. I don't mean to sound like I'm criticizing. I'm just trying to trick you into making a query that I would find more interesting :) It seems like it doesn't make that much of a difference on the low end though.

Comment: @ColleenV as always, no problem, as long as it aims to improve the answer. I'll see what I can do...

Comment: Worth logging in at SEDE to star your first query (for views), but I guess it's possible to [visit the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) without viewing a question; thus making "views" and "visits" two separate things - the [tag:traffic] tag says it's visits/day.

Comment: "*blame this editor.*" bold of you to drag them into the light. Let's hope the editor doesn't try to further deface your posts :P