# Searching for a username on a Meta site under the "Participation" tab throws a 500 server error

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, per-site-meta, participation

Attempting to search for a user on a child meta site's `/users` page, with the "Participation" tab selected, will always fail, and throw a 500 server error in the console.

Here's a .gif example:

[image: Demonstration of me performing a search on gaming.meta.stackexchange.com's User's tab, with the participation tab selected, for "spevacus", and failing]

The console's error message is:

> ```
> GET
> https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/filter?search=spevacus&filter=All&tab=Participation&_=1657206978691
> 500
> ```

This error occurs on child meta sites across the network, including Meta SO.

Could this be looked into and fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is the same thing happening here?: [Searching for moderators on the /users page is broken on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380172/513150)

Comment: @Justin Similar, but different. No error is thrown and the search "completes," the results are just incorrect. That's fine as a standalone bug report.

Comment: This seems to be fixed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulTLh.gif (tested on MathOverflow meta).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fix has been deployed yesterday. I've updated the tag to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: You rock! Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: Thank YOU for reporting it and bringing it to our attention :)