# Searching for moderators in the Moderators tab on the /users page is broken on all meta sites (except MSE)

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, per-site-meta, users-page

Searching for *any* moderator on a meta site (except MSE) in the Moderators tab on the `/users` page does not return any results at all.

Here's a GIF showing how searching in the [Moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) tab works on MSO, for example:

[image: Animated gif of moderators tab in users page on Meta Stack Overflow]

---

Here's a GIF showing how searching for moderators on the *main* site ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)) works, for comparison:

[image: Animated gif of moderators tab in users page on Stack Overflow main]

Comment: Can [repro on meta Code Review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8TmH.png).

Comment: Looking at the implementation, I am 95% sure this never worked for child metas.

Comment: A fix has been deployed today. Please let us know if you are still experiencing issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: As of Jul 12, a fix has been deployed and I have updated the tag to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

This is currently being prioritized as part of bug duty. As such, I've updated the tag to [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).

Answer (score 7):

The Participation tab for users is also broken on all child meta sites as described in [Searching for a username on a Meta site under the "Participation" tab throws a 500 server error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380171/513150):

[image: screenshot of participation tab in users page on Meta Stack Overflow]

Comment: @Justin I'll leave the post here as a roadsign.

Comment: This has now been fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380209/513150