# Filter URL Parameter not considered when navigating between user pages on Metas

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, pagination, users-page

On MSO, when looking at the [users page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users), the [participation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation), [voters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters), and [editors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) tabs have the option to add "filters". The default is "month", but there are also "week", "quarter", "year", and "all".

When clicking a filter like "quarter" a URL parameter is added to the URL "&filter=quarter":

[image]

However, the navigation links at the bottom of the pane do not consider the existing filter. Note the absence of "&filter=quarter" in the link URLs:

[image]

Clicking these links loses the filter which either changes the result set or leads to a blank page since the pagination is based on the initial filter.

**This is the case on all three tabs participation, voters, and editors.**

It is possible to manually navigate to page two with the feature by adding the filter to the URL, *e.g.*, [Page 2 Quarterly Participation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&tab=Participation&filter=quarter), so this is simply an issue with including the filter in the navigation links.

Just for confirmation, I reproduced this behaviour on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/users?tab=Participation&filter=all) ([Screenshot MSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjAq.jpg)) and [Meta Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/users?tab=Participation&filter=all) ([Screenshot MSF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdWk9.jpg)) so this seems to be a per-site meta issue not localised to just MSO.

---

Note: This *is* handled correctly on Stack Overflow's (and other main sites) [Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter), [Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter), and [Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=quarter) tabs:

[image]

Comment: Yep, can confirm that this bug is pretty easily reproducible. Good catch!

Comment: same bug on https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/users (but the default is "week")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry about this! It looks like this issue was missed when we added the option to filter by time period on our meta sites' Users pages.

Before adding the ability to filter by time period to meta sites, we were checking to make sure we weren't applying the time filter URL parameter to a meta site when navigating to a numbered page. That check managed to evade being removed when the feature was implemented.

I have removed the offending piece of code so this issue should be resolved!

I encountered this bug in the wild a few days ago and when I went to report it I saw that you had beaten me to the punch. Since I already had a detailed report to work from, this one was a breeze! Thank you for reporting it to us!