# The Users pages using a query string are redirect on the Way Back Machine. What are the reasons for this?

Tags: support, statistics, users-page, archive

Questions can be archived on [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine), but not sites' Users pages. Wayback Machine shows that the crawler was redirected. Is this by design?

If this is by design, could it be possible for the company or the company together with a group of trusted users, to make an archive and upload it to [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org) or a similar service?

The above is as, in the meantime, that [Make the Users > Voters able to show the previous period (i.e. year 2022)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386281/289691) gets more attention and completes its process.

---

Addendum

The Users pages show which site users are grouped by categories: Reputation, Editors, Voters, New Users, Moderators. On per child Meta, instead of Reputation, it's used Participation. Each category has views (filter / sorting): week, month, quarter, year, all, by creation date, reputation, etc. The navigation between categories and views is handled using query strings (the part of the URL after the question mark `?` ).

> Loading...
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter |
> 17:53:22 April 21, 2022
>
> Got an HTTP 302 response at crawl time
>
> Redirecting to...
>
> /users?tab=reputation&filter=all

The general public usually uses the "Save Now" feature of the Wayback Machine, which works similarly to most search engine web crawlers. It tries to crawl all the linked resources but has limitations. Some limitations are due to following the website instructions for web crawlers. Others are due to the kind of resources they can crawl and download, among other limitations.

The Wayback Machine has an API, and some software and communities help with archiving projects.

---

Related

- [Filter URL Parameter not considered when navigating between user pages on Metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380289/289691)

Comment: related: [Cloudflare blocks Archive.org from saving network profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393231/cloudflare-blocks-archive-org-from-saving-network-profiles)?

Comment: I suspect part of this may be due to privacy concerns / GDPR. If I am a user who has asked for a complete removal of my personal information from the web site, let's say I am being stalked or hunted or whatever, the profile page is the one that is most likely to be helpful to bad people (unlike a username being redacted from my posts). Caching that information on the archive defeats the purpose of asking for removal in the first place. (I don't _know_ that it's intentional, but it's a pretty useful accident if not.)

Comment: @Stuckat1337 The problem with that guessing is that questions can be archived. Questions, answers and comments, have links to users profiles too. I think that user-profile pages can be archived.  In any case, it will be great to have if this "by design" and if due to privacy reasons or for other reasons.

Comment: The point is, if a question has been archived and it links to a users' profile page, they'll get redirected here to see _the current_ page, not to the cached version that showed the profile page _then_. I'm not sure why you think caching the page is better than redirecting to the current page. I sure don't. I care far less about my user name still showing on an archived question page long after I've been redacted than I do about having all of my personal information - which may include where I work, my favorite sportsball team, my cats' and kids' names, etc. - available forever.

Comment: The Way Back Machine don't point users out of the archive, if the page has a link it will try to archive it too, so the link to the user profile will point to the archive of the user profile not to the live user profile page.