# Does the unlinked 'show users by participation' page still work?

Tags: support, bug, participation, hidden-features

Per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226347/1278220),

> On per-site-metas, there is a tab for showing [users by participation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145151/how-is-meta-participation-calculated). According to the tooltip, it shows: *Users most active in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments, and edits).*
>
> The [URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226347/1278220) for this tab is `https://[site].meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation`.
>
> The main site does not have such a tab. But simply by removing the `meta.` part from the above URL, changing it to `https://[site].stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation`, you get another list of users. Although it does not seem to be documented anywhere, it probably orders users by activity on the main.
>
> It works even for <s>Meta Stack Overflow</s> Meta Stack Exchange (which, as it is not a per-site-meta, does have reputation tab and not participation tab in the list of users): https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation.

A [recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/226347#comment1297056_226347) under that answer asks whether this function still works because this just [displays the same listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0ajE.png) as the normal `tab=reputation` link.

Because that's a comment and probably won't get addressed, here's a question asking the same thing:

- Does that feature still work? (It doesn't appear to work, but I may just be doing it completely wrong)
- If it doesn't work, is this a bug?
- And if it's a bug, can it be fixed?
- Is there any other way to access this metric? (like an SEDE query)

Comment: Seems unlikely now. Based on a quick experiment, putting random non-existent options after `tab=` will return the same as `tab=reputation` (probably as default fallback behavior)

Comment: A natural question is whether now that this no longer works on the main, whether there were some changes in the participation tab on meta, too.
A random example [from the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506175357/https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation) showing that this "hidden feature" existed in the past.

Comment: The answer linked in this question was deleted by a moderator. (I suppose it is understandable - the answer became obsolete.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not. The filter was too resource-intensive for non-Meta sites and was disabled for them in June of 2022. It will just display the reputation tab if you try to access it on sites which have their own reputation (main sites and Meta Stack Exchange).